# Android Java progressdialog from Baseadapter

Tags: java, android, download

On my android app, I have my own BaseAdapter, in this I have a click button listener with the following code:

```
btnShareFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            videoMoreLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
            final String id = videoIDs[position];
            videoActions = new VideoActions();
            hfu = new HttpFileUpload(videoPathURL[position], token);

            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Preparing video to share...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            if (!isOnline()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        activity.getString(R.string.noInternetConnection),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                try {
                    String arr[] = videoPathURL[position].split("/upload/videos/");
                    final String finalVideoName = (arr[arr.length-1]);

                    File DoutFile = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                            File.separator + "vidytape_shared" + File.separator + finalVideoName);

                    if(!DoutFile.exists()){

                        pDialog.show();

                        String downloadResult = videoActions.downloadToShare(token, activity, id, videoPathURL[position], finalVideoName);
                        if (downloadResult.equalsIgnoreCase("POST_FAILURE") || downloadResult.equalsIgnoreCase("FAILURE_102")) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    activity,
                                    activity.getString(R.string.someErrorOccurred),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        /*if(hfu.Download_File_To_Share(finalVideoName, videoPathURL[position])){
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //pDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "ERRO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }*/


                    }

                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    share.setType("video/*");
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(DoutFile));
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                    activity.startActivity(share);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            activity.getString(R.string.facebookNotInstalled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Now here you have the function downloadToShare from the class VideoActions:

```
public String downloadToShare(String token, Activity activity, String videoID, String videoPath, String videoName) {

    this.token      = token;
    this.activity   = activity;
    this.videoId    = videoID;
    this.videoPath  = videoPath;
    this.videoName  = videoName;

    DownloadToShareClass downloadAction = new DownloadToShareClass();

    try {
        return downloadAction.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
} // Close download
```

And now the downloadToShare class:

```
class DownloadToShareClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { 

    String response = null;

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Preparing video to share...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                HttpFileUpload hfu = new HttpFileUpload(videoPath, token);
                hfu.Download_File_To_Share(videoName, videoPath);

                return "SUCESSFULLY";
    }

} // Close DownloadClass
```

Now the download_file_to_share:

```
boolean Download_File_To_Share(String fileName, String urlToDownload) {

    boolean downloadResult;
    try {
        downloadResult = DownloadFileToShare(fileName, urlToDownload);
        return downloadResult;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And for the last the DownloadFileToShare:

```
// Download video
boolean DownloadFileToShare(String filename, String urlToDownload)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                File.separator + "vidytape_shared" + File.separator + filename);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (fout != null)
            fout.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

My Problem is as you can see on my BaseAdapter code, I'm showing a progress dialog, but it only is shown after all the rest finish (the video download). What is the problem here ? I want that the progressDialog shows when the video is being downloaded...

Thanks in advance

**I've found a solution to my own problem. From my BaseAdapter I changed my click listener code to the following and it's working perfectly now:**

```
btnShareFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            videoMoreLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
            hfu = new HttpFileUpload(videoPathURL[position], token);

            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.preparingVideoToShare));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            if (!isOnline()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        activity.getString(R.string.noInternetConnection),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                try {
                    String arr[] = videoPathURL[position].split("/upload/videos/");
                    final String finalVideoName = (arr[arr.length-1]);

                    final File DoutFile = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                            File.separator + "vidytape_shared" + File.separator + finalVideoName);

                    if(!DoutFile.exists()){

                        pDialog.show();

                        (new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                final String a = hfu.Download_File_To_Share(finalVideoName, videoPathURL[position]);
                                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (!a.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(activity, 
                                                    activity.getResources().getString(R.string.someErrorOccurred), 
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                            share.setType("video/*");
                                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(DoutFile));
                                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                                    "" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                                            share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                                            activity.startActivity(share);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })).start();

                    } else {
                        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        share.setType("video/*");
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(DoutFile));
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                "" + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                        share.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                        activity.startActivity(share);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if(pDialog.isShowing()){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity,
                            activity.getString(R.string.facebookNotInstalled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

I hope it can help someone too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add code to show progressbar in onPreExecute in class DownloadToShareClass which extends AsyncTask ?

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

From the above link -- 
onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.

```
class DownloadToShareClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private ProgressDialog mdialog;
public DownloadToShareClass(yourActivity activity) {
    mdialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mdialog.show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
} 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (mdialog.isShowing()) {
        mdialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No, it's not working... ProgressDialog just appears after download is completed...

Comment: Did you able to fix it ? Only one another reason I could think of is instead of  DownloadToShareClass downloadAction = new DownloadToShareClass(); please declare downloadAction as a private static.

Comment: Yes i was able to fix with the code in my edit! Thank you for your answer Praveeno